# Unity - Making collision around the screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wish to create `EdgeCollider2D`-s around my camera's view. 
To do that I use the following code:

```
public class CreateWorldEdgeCollision2D : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject prefab;

    private void Awake() {

        GameObject[] colladas = new GameObject[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < colladas.Length; i++) {
            colladas[i] = Instantiate(prefab);
            colladas[i].transform.position = Vector3.zero;
        }

        var left = colladas[0].GetComponent<EdgeCollider2D>();
        var right = colladas[1].GetComponent<EdgeCollider2D>();
        var top = colladas[2].GetComponent<EdgeCollider2D>();
        var bottom = colladas[3].GetComponent<EdgeCollider2D>();

        left.points = new Vector2[] { Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Vector3.zero), 
            Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0,Camera.main.pixelHeight)) };
        right.points = new Vector2[] { Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Camera.main.pixelWidth,0)), 
            Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Camera.main.pixelWidth,Camera.main.pixelHeight)) };
        top.points = new Vector2[] { Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Camera.main.pixelWidth,0)),
            Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Camera.main.pixelWidth,Camera.main.pixelHeight)) };
        bottom.points = new Vector2[] { Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Vector3.zero),
            Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Camera.main.pixelWidth,0)) };
    }
}
```

I dragged the `prefab` from the inspector, it's just a `GameObject` with an `EdgeCollider2D` component on it. I instantiate 4, set their position to idle. Then I get their `EdgeCollider2D` components.

Then I assign their points, which are just 2 points for each of the colliders, for example:

- left: from bottom left to top left.
- right: from bottom right to top right

and so on.

The problem is, when I apply the `Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint` to the given value, it becomes `Vector3 { 0,0,0.7 }` and I have no clue why because I used this method before and it worked just fine. How can I make the collision around the screen?

Comment: I guess it is z position issue if your camera is in perspective mode

Comment: Yep, it's persp. However the canvas is 2D, I had no clue what to set its Z to, so I left it at zero. What do you think I should set the Z to?

Comment: Lol I set up an ortho cam and it works just fine xd

Comment: Thanks for the heads up btw. In case someone else needs a solution, I wrote my working code as an answer.

Comment: When its perspective you need accurate position of the point. You can put a cube on  the desire position to see and then can use your code to convert that point.

Comment: Yup someday I plan to mess around with that, but for now I'm happy with the current result :D The other camera doesn't render anything anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To anyone who needs this solution, just use an ortho camera. And I made a mistake in the code, so here's the correct one:

```
public class CreateWorldEdgeCollision2D : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject prefab;
    private Camera ortho;
    private void Awake() {
        ortho = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("OrthoCam").GetComponent<Camera>();
        GameObject[] colladas = new GameObject[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < colladas.Length; i++) {
            colladas[i] = Instantiate(prefab);
            colladas[i].transform.position = Vector3.zero;
        }

        var left = colladas[0].GetComponent<EdgeCollider2D>();
        var right = colladas[1].GetComponent<EdgeCollider2D>();
        var top = colladas[2].GetComponent<EdgeCollider2D>();
        var bottom = colladas[3].GetComponent<EdgeCollider2D>();


        var testshit1 = ortho.pixelHeight;
        var testshit2 = ortho.pixelWidth;

        var test1 = ortho.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(testshit1, 0));


        left.points = new Vector2[] { ortho.ScreenToWorldPoint(Vector3.zero), 
            ortho.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0,ortho.pixelHeight)) };
        right.points = new Vector2[] { ortho.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(ortho.pixelWidth,0)), 
            ortho.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(ortho.pixelWidth,ortho.pixelHeight)) };
        top.points = new Vector2[] { ortho.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0,ortho.pixelHeight)),
            ortho.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(ortho.pixelWidth,ortho.pixelHeight)) };
        bottom.points = new Vector2[] { ortho.ScreenToWorldPoint(Vector3.zero),
            ortho.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(ortho.pixelWidth,0)) };
    }
}
```

(The mistake was the top collision - it had wrong coordinates).